# Do all the curves become straight line in limit

Tags: limits, differential-geometry, curves

Do all the curves become straight line in limit of their length to zero.

I know $$ \triangle L=\sqrt{(\triangle x)^2 + (\triangle y)^2}$$

And when  $ \triangle L ,\triangle x , \triangle y$ $\longrightarrow 0$

$$ d L=\sqrt{(d x)^2 + (d y)^2}=dx \sqrt{....}$$

which $\sqrt{\cdot}$ is defined according to our curve equation.

So, does the curve becomes straight line when $\triangle L \longrightarrow 0$ ?

Comment: All "nice" curves are practically indistinguishable from lines if you zoom in enough. Exceptions include the [Koch snowflake](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/65/Kochsim.gif).

Comment: It's so provided the curvature remains finite.  Deep zoom on a spiral always look the same.

Comment: The [Weierstrass function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function) might be of interest.

Answer (score 0):

All curves which are everywhere differentiable become straight lines (in the sense you are trying to describe, which can in fact be made into a rigorous definition) as the diameter of the region examined goes to zero.

And the proof of that does go along the lines of your reasoning.

However, curves which are not everywhere differentiable do not have that property:  Consider $y=|x|$ near $x=0$.

You might think that you can have a fractal curve which is everywhere differentiable, but which does not become straight lines in sufficiently small regions.  However, fractal curves are not everywhere differentiable.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it can be formulated this way.

Take a function $f(x)$. Also, consider points $x_0$ and $x_0+dx$. The line that goes through the points is

$y=\alpha x-\alpha x_0 +f(x_0)$

where $\alpha=\frac{f(x_0+dx)-f(x_0)}{dx}$

Then, we can define when a curve between the points tends to a line, as below

$\forall\epsilon>0 \exists dx>0|\forall x\in (x_0,x_0+dx) \rightarrow |f(x)-\alpha x+\alpha x_0 -f(x_0)|<\epsilon$

Using triangle inequality, we can have

$|f(x)-\alpha x+\alpha x_0 -f(x_0)|\leq |f(x)-f(x_0)|+|\alpha||x-x_0|$

Assuming $|\alpha|<\infty$ , we need to make sure that

$lim_{x\rightarrow x_0}|f(x)-f(x_0)|=0$

So, I think, for a function $f(x)$, the requirement is to have

$lim_{x\rightarrow x_0}f(x)=f(x_0)$

Comment: thanks, that's what I wanted.

Comment: I hate to point this out, but this answer is wrong. The requirement on $f(x)$ that is stated assures continuity but not differntiability. $f(x)=|x|$ meets the requirement but does not look like a line segment in sufficiently small regions centered on zero.

Comment: Wow, you have been thinking about it all the time?

Comment: I think, it really depends on how you define a segment on a curve. With the segment that you have defined around the point $x=0$, you surely will not get a line. So, you fix the centre and narrow the interval. But, the way, I have defined it, is to take a point $x_0$, as the lower bound of the interval and the upper bound would approach to $x_0$. With this interval, you do not get into trouble.

Comment: :) why don't you take more credits off me...